# How to get filepath instead of url with <link href and <script src

Tags: javascript, file, href, src

I want to make a javascript file uploader. The location of css for this uploader is "~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.css" and the js location is "~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js" . I want to do the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>      
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <ul id="separate-list"></ul>

    <script src="~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function createUploader() {
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                element: document.getElementById('demo'),
                listElement: document.getElementById('separate-list'),
                action: '~/Scripts/fileuploader/do-nothing.htm'
            });
        }
        window.onload = createUploader;     
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

However, `<link href="~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.css"` and `<script src="~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js"` become `http://localhost:1304/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/Index/~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js?_=1325540158292`
and `http://localhost:1304/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/Index/~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js`?

How can I change this so that it does `~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js` instead of  `http://localhost:1304/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/Index/~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to put that ~ symbol to there? If your html file (or php I don't know) are at the place where that you mean with that ~ symbol, deleting ~/ symbols will solve the problem.

`<link href="Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

`<script src="Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: that does not work either, but it is there.this does work in a different cshtml file <link rel="Stylesheet" href="@UI.StaticContent("~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.css")" type="text/css" media="all" />